# Hiding and showing button on pickerView selection

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10, uipickerview

I am new to swift. I have a `viewController`

[image]

Initially the pickerView is hidden but it appears on clicking on textField then it hides again. I want the button hide upon `pickeriew` selection and then unhide after selection. This is how i am doing it.

```
   func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    pickerView.isHidden = false
    return false
}
```

I can hide the backButton like `backButton.isHidden = true` but it won't show when the selection is done.

Answer (score 2):

Just make visible the back button when picker value is selected and hide the pickerview

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, 
inComponent component: Int)
{
backButton.isHidden = false
pickerView.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Powerful and smart solution

Comment: @santosh please have a look at this as well if you have time. I'd be grateful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361686/how-to-restrict-button-click

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to show the picker view during textfield selection, then you need to add picker view as textfield's input view. You can refer this link also https://blog.apoorvmote.com/uipickerview-as-inputview-to-uitextfield-in-swift/